# Download ODS/XLS from Rest API Java

Tags: java, angularjs, rest, file, ods

I'm trying to make a download of a ODS file (Open Office's Calc file).
I'm using Java for back end and AngularJS for front end.
This is my code of the front end where I receive and download the file:

```
vm.downloadModel = () => {
  DataFactory.GET(`${URL.CTM_ODS()}/rotas/modelo`, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/octet-stream' } }).then(response => {
    let file = new Blob([response], { type: 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet' });
    let url = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    let downloadLink = angular.element('<a></a>');
    downloadLink.attr('href', url.createObjectURL(file));
    downloadLink.attr('target', '_self');
    downloadLink.attr('download', 'Model_Routes_OD.ods');
    downloadLink[0].click();
  });
}
```

This is my endpoint on my back end:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/modelo")
@ResponseBody
public ResponseEntity<ByteArrayResource> getModelo() throws IOException {
    String path = "C:\\Model_Routes_OD.ods";
    File file = new File(path);
    Path pathObj = Paths.get(file.getAbsolutePath());
    ByteArrayResource resource = new ByteArrayResource(Files.readAllBytes(pathObj));
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment; filename=" + file.getName());
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE);
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_LENGTH, String.valueOf(Files.readAllBytes(pathObj).length));
    headers.add(HttpHeaders.TRANSFER_ENCODING, "binary");

    return new ResponseEntity<>(resource, headers, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

The file that is downloaded came corrupted! My file has 13Kb and when it downloads shows 21Kb, when I try to open he says that the file is "broken" and he can try to fix it but, without success.

Comment: did you try get api direct in browser ?

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and api is working fine.
You don't need to explicitly handle file at frontend, instead you can just download it.

Example code for above scenario:

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', []);

app.controller('Download', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.download = function(){
        var url = "http://localhost:8080/modelo"
            window.open(url, "_self");
    }
});
```

I am able to download file perfectly and here is complete code for this [example](https://github.com/kumarhemant10/sample-projects-springboot/tree/master/filehandler)

Comment: Same error! Maybe my file is messing something? I'm using UTF-8 so probably when he pass the bytes he's messing with something! Also, I tried sending an object that have the bytes in a byte[] variable inside and, the JSON generated was incomplete! Was  like
`{
"name":"Model_Routes_OD.ods",
"path":"C:\",
"bytes":" 'He put some bytes here but don't close with " and don't finish the JSON with }`

Comment: I retried your code and it returned HTTP 401, I need headers to pass my Authorization token. However, you said that my API was working fine? That means you can download and open the file with my API code?

Comment: I've made an object with 3 variables, path and name being String and base64 being a byte[], when the front end receives this object and I pass to Blob like this `let file = new Blob([response.base64], { type: 'application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet' });` he makes a valid .ods file, I can even open it but, it's a ".doc" file with a text of the base64 variable.